# publishing the application giving error on screen shot attachment

Tags: android

i am going to publish my android app on android market i fileed all the information as screen shot ,application icon 0f 512*512 size every thing is ok and when i click on publish button following below error is coming  for screen shot..

Screenshots:
320 x 480, 480 x 800, 480 x 854,
1280 x 720, 1280 x 800
24 bit PNG or JPEG (no alpha)
Full bleed, no border in art
You may upload screenshots in landscape orientation. The thumbnails will appear to be rotated, but the actual images and their orientations will be preserved.

and display a message that "please correct the error below and try to save again"

i used 480*800 size of image of type .png then what is the problem and when i attaching the screen shot and uploading it it uploaded successful and when i deleting attached screen shot it is not deleting...i upload 4 screen shot..

Comment: Most probably your png has aplha channel. If you cannot remove alpha channel, convert to jpg format and use the jpg images.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and as with Sarwar Erfan above I converted them to JPG (100% but dont know if that's significant) and it cleared the errors

Comment: Thanks. Had the exact same problem, converting the pngs to jpg and re-uploading helped. Really extremely frustrating...